# Simplify square root in fraction?

Tags: arithmetic

Can $\frac{4+\sqrt{40}}{2}$ be simplified to $2+\sqrt{10}$ manually?

Comment: $\sqrt{40}=2\sqrt{10}$...

Comment: For more information,here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root

Comment: Too trivial to be discussed here.

Answer (score 11):

$$\frac{4+\sqrt{40}}{2} = \frac{4+\sqrt{4\times 10}}{2} =\frac{4+\sqrt{4}\times\sqrt{10}}{2} = \frac{4+2\sqrt{10}}{2} = 2+\sqrt{10}$$

Answer (score 4):

Observe that

1. $\dfrac{A+B}{C}=\dfrac{A}{C}+\dfrac{B}{C}$,
2. $2=\sqrt{4}$,
3. and $\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b} }$.

Then

$$\frac{4+\sqrt{40}}{2} = \frac{4}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{40}}{2} =2+\frac{\sqrt{40}}{\sqrt{4}}=2+\sqrt{\frac{40}{4}} =  2+\sqrt{10}.$$