# Prove: $p-mq | f(m)$ where $m$ is any integer

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, roots

How to prove that $p-mq \mid f(m)$ where $m$ is any integer,

$$f(x) = A_0 + A_1 x + A_2 x^2 + ... + A_{n-1} x^{n-1} + A_n x^n$$

$$f(x)∈ ℤ[x]$$

$p/q$ is a zero for $f(x)$ and $p$ and $q$ are coprime $⇒ \, ∃u,w ∈ ℤ \mid 1 = up + wq$.

Comment: suppose $f(x)=a+bx$ can you do???

Comment: Maybe, if I do induction for n. That would be the base case.

Comment: do that first... then let me know if you get some idea for other $n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note first that for any $p,q$, $q^nf\bigl(\frac pq\bigr)$ is an integer. Now if $\frac pq$ is a root of $f$,
\begin{align*}
q^nf(m)=q^nf(m)-q^nf\Bigl(\frac pq\Bigr)&=\sum_{k=0}^n A_k q^{n-k}\Bigl(m^kq^k - p^k\Bigr)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n A_k q^{n-k}(mq-p)\Bigl((mq)^{k-1}+(mq)^{k-1}p+\dots+p^{k-1}\Bigr)
\end{align*}
which proves $q^nf(m)$ is divisible by $p-mq$. As $p$ and $q$ are coprime, $p-mq$ and $q^n$ are coprime too, so that, by Gauß's lemma, $p-mq$ divides $f(m)$.

Comment: I don't get why f(m) - q^n f(p/q) is equal to that sum.

Comment: Instead of [ Ak*q^(n-k)*(m^k*q^k-p^k) ], I get [ Ak*(m^k-q^(n-k)*p^k)]

Comment: That comes from $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n A_kx^k$, replacing $x$ with $\dfrac pq$ and cancelling the denominators with (part of) $q^n$.

Comment: You should get $A^k(m^k q^n-q^{n-k}p^k)$, then you can factor out $q^{n-k}$.

Comment: The sum  $\,= \color{#c00}{q^n}f(m)-q^n f(p/q)\ $

Comment: Oops! I wondered what was the problem, and forgot to check that side of the formula! Thanks for pointing it! Proof completed.

Comment: @Ronald I added a proof of the nonmonic polynomial division algorithm to help out with problems like this - see the link in my answer.

Comment: Second time I have an accepted answer with a downvote…

Answer (score 1):

By [nonmonic polynomial division algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242) $\, q^n f = (qx\!-\!p) g + k\,$ for $\,g\in\Bbb Z[x],\ n\in\Bbb N,k\in\Bbb Z.$ Evaluating at $\:x=p/q\:$ yields $\:k=0.\ $ Evaluating at $\:x =m\:$ yields $\:\color{#c00}{qm\!-\!p\mid q^n}\color{#0a0}{f(m)}.\,$ But $\,(qm\!-\!p,q)=(p,q)\!=\!1,\,$ so by Euclid $\,(\color{#c00}{qm\!-\!p,q^n})=1,\,$ therefore $\,qm\!-\!p\mid \color{#0a0}{f(m)}.$