# Polynomial factorisation for unique factor domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring

> Suppose $R$ is a UFD and $f \in R[X]$ such that $\deg f > 0$ and $f$ has a root $\alpha \in R$. Show that $f = (X - \alpha) g$ for some $g \in R[X]$. (Suggestion: Write $f = a_0 + a_1 X + \dotsc + a_n X^n$, $g = b_0 + b_1 X + \dotsc + b_{n-1} X^{n-1}$ where $a_i \in R$, $b_i \in Q$ where $Q$ is the field of fractions of $R$. Expand $(X - \alpha)g$ and use that $\alpha \in R$ and $R$ is a ring to show that $b_{n-1},\dotsc,b_0 \in R$.)

This is the question I am attempting from my textbook. My initial thought was to use the division algorithm, but this does not seem to work. Can anyone tell me how to do this for a UFD?

Comment: Please note that questions in picture form are frowned upon here. A few explanatory pictures are fine, but a question should be understandable even without them. You can learn how to typeset math from our [basic MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an UFD. An integral domain is enough. Use the division algorithm in the quotient field and show that the resulting $g$ is contained in $R[X]$.

Some details:

We have $$a_0+a_1X + \dotsb a_nX^n = (X-\alpha)(b_0 + b_1X + \dotsb + b_{n-1}X^{n-1})$$

Considering the coefficients at $X^n$ shows $b_{n-1}=a_n \in R$. We proceed like this and conclude $b_{n-2} \in R$ by looking at $X^{n-1}$ and so on...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22180/discussion-between-user43290-and-moos).

Comment: Euclidean division works in any commutative ring with unity, as long as the divisor's leading coefficient is a unit...

Comment: Yes, thats precisely what this calculation is supposed to show...

Comment: @A.P.And it works in the nonmonic case with a little massaging, see the [pseudo-Division Algorithm.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242)

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate $f(x) - f(α)$      (this is equal to $f(x)$, due to $α$ being a root of $f$).

A factor of $(x-α)$ can be taken out after some manipulation.

So you will now have $f(x)=(x-α)g(x)$

$g(x)$ will most likely look quite messy, but if you collect like terms and relabel these as your $b_i$'s you will be able to see that $g$ is in fact in $R[x]$ too, due to $R$ being a ring.