# Express the polynomial in the form p(x) = (x+1) Q(x) +R where (x+1) is the divisor, Q(x) is the quotient and R is the remainder

Tags: polynomials

Express the polynomial in the form p(x) = (x+1) Q(x) +R where (x+1) is the divisor, Q(x) is the quotient and R is the remainder,

Hey I would just like to know how to solve this as the question had me confused I don’t know if I am suppose to do long division on write it out like in the question, thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Carry out the polynomial division.

Comment: Yes, long division is the way to go. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: When it gives me the values yes, but I can’t see what to use as the dividend

Comment: @JeffWiggle When you divide $p(x)$ by $x+1$, you get $Q(x)$ with a remainder of $R$.

Comment: Oh ok thank you

Answer (score 0):

Any textbook would tell you to do polynomial division. Personally, I think polynomial division is too opaque of a technique to use before you know how to solve a question like this without it. So here is an example using what basically amounts to long division, but much less mysterious.

Take $p(x) = x^3+2x^2-3x+5$. We want to write this of the form $(x+1)Q(x) + R$ for some polynomial $Q$, and some polynomial $R$ with smaller degree than $x+1$ (which is to say, $R$ is a constant). We do this by building $Q$ term by term, reducing the degree of the remainder until we have our constant $R$.

The fact that the highest degree term of $p$ is $x^3$ means that the highest degree term of $Q$ must be $x^2$. So we add $(x+1)x^2$, and simultaneously subtract $x^3+x^2$ from the remainder. This doesn't change the value, but it lets us start on building our $Q$:
$$
p(x) = (x+1)x^2 - (x^3+x^2) + x^3+2x^2-3x+5\\
= (x+1)x^2 + x^2-3x+5
$$
We have now successfully gone from a third degree remainder (all of $p$) to a second degree remainder. We are one step closer to a constant remainder. Next step: The highest degree term of the remainder is $x^2$, so the next term to add to $Q$ must be $x$:
$$
p(x) = (x+1)x^2 - (x^2 + x) + (x+1)x + x^2-3x+5\\
= (x+1)(x^2+x) -4x+5
$$
And finally, in the last step, we see that the leading term of the current remainder is $-4x$, so the final term to add to $Q$ must be $-4$:
$$
p(x) = (x+1)(x^2+x) + (x+1)(-4) - (-4x-4) -4x+5\\
= (x+1)(x^2+x-4) + 9
$$
And there we have it: $Q(x) =  x^2+x-4$ and $R = 9$. If you do the long division, you might recognize how each step in the long division corresponds to something I did here, and vice versa, but long division is something of a mystery if one *doesn't* know that this is the process that lies behind it.

Also, I have been extra verbose here. If I were to give this problem on a test, I wouldn't necessarily expect more from an answer than, say,

> $$
> p(x) = x^3+2x^2-3x+5\\
> = (x+1)x^2 + x^2-3x+5\\
> = (x+1)(x^2+x) -4x+5\\
> = (x+1)(x^2+x-4) + 9
> $$

All-in-all more transparent and easier to follow than polynomial long division.

Answer (score 0):

Put $\,a = -1\,$ in $\ p(x)\, =\, (x-a)\,\dfrac{p(x)-p(a)}{\ x\,-\,a} + p(a),\,$ the [Polynomial Remainder Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3316843/242).

The quotient is exact by the [Polynomial Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3316843/242), and is computable by the [Polynomial Division Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3094293/242) (which also computes the remainder).