# Is there a Euclidean algorithm in $k[x,x^{-1},y]$?

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, and let $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ be the polynomial ring in $x,x^{-1},y$.

> Is there a [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) in $k[x,x^{-1},y]$?

Two relevant questions are: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136654/help-proving-polynomials-division-algorithm-in-rx-where-r-is-a-domain) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316752/division-algorithm-for-multivariate-polynomials).

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Euclidean domain (i.e. an integral domain with a Euclidean function that allows the Euclidean algorithm to find gcd's, like the absolute value for $\Bbb Z$, or the degree for $k[x]$) must necessarily be a principle ideal domain. The ideal $(x+1, y)\subseteq k[x, x^{-1}, y]$ is not principal. So there is no Euclidean algorithm on your ring.

Comment: Thank you. Same answer for $k[x,y]$?

Comment: @user237522 Exactly (except there one can use the ideal $(x, y)$, which looks a bit nicer). Imagine using the extended Euclidean algorithm to write $1 = f\cdot x + g\cdot y$. That's clearly not going to work. Your case requires a little more care since $x$ is invertible, but not much.

Comment: Thank you.  $k[x,x^{-1},y]$ is a UFD, isn't it? ($k[x,y]$ is a UFD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).

Comment: @user237522 Yes, I believe it is. Which in particular means that gcd's exist. You just can't use the Euclidean algorithm to get to them.

Comment: Thank you. (I have also seen this argument).