# $\begin{align}&(x\! -\! a,f_1(x),\ldots,f_r(x))\\ =\ &(x\! -\! a,f_1(a),\ldots,f_r(a))\end{align}\ $ [Ideal evaluation = mod reduction]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, euclidean-algorithm, string-theory

$\begin{align}&(x\! -\! a,f_1(x),\ldots,f_r(x))\\[.1em] =\ &(x\! -\! a,f_1(a),\ldots,f_r(a))\end{align}\ $  [Ideal evaluation = mod reduction]

I am solving Aluffi chapter 0. I am completely stuck on this question.

Let R be a commutative ring, $a \in R$, and $f_1(x),\ldots, f_r(x) \in R[x]$.  Prove the equality of ideals

1. $(f_1(x),\ldots,f_r(x),x - a) = (f_1(a),\ldots,f_r(a),x - a)$
2. Prove the useful substitution trick
   $\frac{R[x]}{(f_1(x),\ldots,f_r(x), x - a)} \cong \frac{R}{(f_1(a),\ldots,f_r(a))}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: as in Euclidean algorithm for gcds, [ideals are preserved by:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3533044/242) mod out a generator by another

$$x\!-\!a,\, f \in I \iff x\!-\!a,\!\!\!\!\! \overbrace{f\,-\, q\, (x-a)}^{\textstyle f(a) = f\bmod x\!-a}\!\!\!\!\!\in I $$

where we used [Polynomial Remainder Theorem,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3316843/242) i.e. $\,f(a) = f\bmod x\!-\!a\,$ .

**Remark** $ $ More generally ideals are prserved by any [unimodular transformations of generators](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863501/242) ("change of basis")

Comment: how do we know that the shifted ideal agrees with the ideal.

Comment: @joe Hint: the above equivalence implies that each of your two ideals contains the generators of the other ideal, so each contains the other, so they are equal.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Thanks this makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You can divide each polynomial by $x-a$, obtaining
$$f_k(x)=q_k(x)(x-a)+f_k(a),\quad k=1,\dots,r.$$

Comment: how do know that $(q_1(x)(x- a) + f_1(a),\ldots, q_r(x)(x - a) + f_r(a)) = (f_1(a), \ldots f_r(a))$

Comment: This is not true. You have to consider the quotient by $x-a$ to obtain $R$, using  the 3rd isomorphism theorem.