# How do you calculate a modulo between equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-algorithm

I'm preparing for an exam and, looking at older exams I stumbled across this question:

Compute $gcd(a(x), b(x))$ where $a(x) = x^3+x+2$ and $b(x)=x^2+x+1$
And the solution is $x+3$

So, I know that the procedure of this, using Euclid's algorithm is:
$\gcd(a,b)$ becomes $\gcd(R_{x^2+x+1}(x^3+x+2))$
But how would I compute $x^3+x+2 \equiv x+3 $ (mod $x^2+x+1$)?

Comment: Hint:$$x^3+x+2=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)+x+3$$

Comment: I explained an optimization that is often helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute $\,a\bmod b\,$ we can use the (Euclidean) [polynomial division algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242) to divide  $a$ by $b,\,$ which  yields the remainder $ =a\bmod b,\,$ same as for integers.

However here there is a nice optimization that is available. Namely we have $\,b\mid x^3-1\,$ therefore  $\,a\bmod b = (a\bmod x^3\!-1)\bmod b.\,$ But computing $\bmod \color{#c00}{x^3\!-1}\,$ is easy since we can use the rewrite rule $\,\color{#c00}{x^3\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}x^{\color{#c00}3n}\equiv \color{#c00}1^n\equiv 1\,$ to quickly reduce every polynomial to one of degree $\le 2,\,$ e.g. your $\,a = \color{#c00}{x^3}\!+\!x\!+\!2$ $\equiv \color{#c00}1\!+\!x\!+\!2$ $\equiv x\!+\!3.\,$  This is a special case of the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242).

Answer (score 2):

[Polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) yields $(x^3+x+2)=(x^2+x+1)(x-1)+x+3$:

$$\begin{align}& \underline{x-1}\\
x^2+x+1&)x^3+x+2\\
&\underline{x^3+x^2+x}
\\
&&-x^2+2\\
&&\underline{-x^2-x-1}\\
&&x+3
\end{align}$$

Comment: format editing is welcomed ;-)